# Can't install Pillow on Cygwin Python for Windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, python-imaging-library

I tried to install the latest version of Pillow on Windows through Cygwin with `pip install Pillow`, but I get the error message:

```
In file included from _imagingtk.c:19:0:

/usr/include/tk.h:76:23: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory

 # include <X11/Xlib.h>

                       ^

compilation terminated.

In file included from Tk/tkImaging.c:52:0:

/usr/include/tk.h:76:23: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory

 # include <X11/Xlib.h>

                       ^

compilation terminated.

Building using 8 processes

gcc -shared -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -L. build/temp.cygwin-1.7.30-x86_64-2.7/_imagingtk.o build/temp.cygwin-1.7.30-x86_64-2.7/Tk/tkImaging.o -L/usr/lib
-L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -ltcl8.5 -ltk8.5 -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.cygwin-1.7.30-x86_64-2.7/PIL/_imagingtk.dll

gcc: error: build/temp.cygwin-1.7.30-x86_64-2.7/_imagingtk.o: No such file or directory

gcc: error: build/temp.cygwin-1.7.30-x86_64-2.7/Tk/tkImaging.o: No such file or directory

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

---------------------------------------- Cleaning up... Command /usr/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_User /pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-7Gv1dT-record/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_User/pillow

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log) UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 35: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It's failing because it can't find X11, which is particularly confusing because I'm on a Windows computer and X11 is Linux software. I don't like relying on the precompiled version because there is no support.

Comment: Looks like Pillow depends on Xlib. You have to install the xorg packages for cygwin.

Comment: Are you aware of Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) repository? Both `requests` and `Pillow` are available there...

Comment: Yep sorry, I just edited my question (that's where I originally got Pillow from), but I don't like using the pre-compiled versions because there's no update support.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I installed both the Cygwin 32-bit and General development packages for X11 and that fixed the problem, thank you.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

As always, the answer here is to ditch Cygwin and use a better shell.

Comment: Cygwin is much more than just a shell, and a self-answer of "I give up" doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Agree, Cygwin is not a shell. Its a complete Posix environment and helps take the Doh! out of Windohs. Out of all the python libraries I depend on, Image which depends on Pillow are the only missing ones. Cryptography is getting to be an issue though because of Rust build dependency.  Cygwin FTW!

Comment: More-over, `Cygwin` is a very-mature standalone UN*X environment in Windows, complete with obscure things such-as NIS...  and other places where `WSL` or `WSL2` are still somewhat lacking. It's sad to see its use decline. But for those of us who just "can't" (won't) use putty or a "better" SSH/shell tool, it's a godsend.

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for a similar problem, this is because OP failed to install many of the X11 libraries that are included with Cygwin. Yes, if you're using Cygwin, you're using "Linux" tools, in a sense (it's a standalone POSIX compliant environment for Windows ... and yes, you can run X11 servers and clients with it).

Other than that, my current problem is with some of the graphics libraries (eg. openjpeg), on a current version of Cygwin (3.4.9) and Windows (11)... and this was "a hit" in that search.